# Querying multiple collections using Mongo Template

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

```
Products : {

           id : 1
}

Customer : {
     id : 2
}
```

List<> customerProductIds = new Arraylist();

I want to query both product and customer and check if customer ids and product ids are there in the list if yes return combined list as object.

***Note*** : *we don't have any connection between two collections.*

Query which I'm using is

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().from("Product")

        .localField("_id").foreignField(" customer._id").as("entity");

    AggregationResults<Object> entities =

        this.template.aggregate(

            Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation,

                Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("id").in(ids))),

            Customer.class, Object.class);
```

But it doesn't work. I'm looking for a  better approach. Any suggestions?

***Note*** : *Probably the lookup is working as the joins in SQL where in it is looking for foreign key - primary key relation which doesn't apply here as both collections are independent.*

*Initially I had two different queries and adding it to a list.But I need to implement pagination for the combined list. If I use two queries approach I won't be able to handle pagination for combined list.*

*Is there any option in Map reduce which I can implement for this requirement ?*

*Hope the scenario is cleared.*

Comment: Why not do two queries for each collection and return the results ?

Comment: Initially I have done that. Two different queries and adding it to a  list.But I need to implement pagination for the combined list. If I use two quries approach it would be difficult to handle pagination.

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit `Product.class.getName()`. This will give full class name with path.
You can either use  `Product.class.getSimpleName()` or just use the collection name directly.
Another thing is for foriegn field you shouldn't give `customer._id`. just specify as `_id`

```
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup()
.from("ProductCollectionName")
.localField("fieldNameInCustomerCollection")
.foreignField("fieldNameInProductCollection").as("entity");

AggregationResults<Object> entities =
    this.template.aggregate(
        Aggregation.newAggregation(lookupOperation,
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("id").in(ids))), 
            Customer.class, Object.class);
```

Comment: But will it serve the requirement , because when I say localField("_id").foreignField(" customer._id") , wont it check whether local _id and foreign_id are same. ( as in sql joins). ?   Here both the collections are not having any link its just two collection.

Comment: yes, but you were giving collection name it self wrong.  Edited my answer a bit

Comment: you were giving collection name as wrong (i.e. Product.class.getName().).

Comment: I did change it.The thing is even if I use this query this is not giving proper result.because customer.id can never be equal to product.id, both collection  don't have any link , they are independent.when I use lookup it actually try to join using both ids.

Comment: if there is no link then how will this work? That is the whole point of LookUp

Comment: Yup. That's what I indicated in the post it's not working . Looking for any other suggestions,other than lookup,  through which I can achieve my req

Comment: there is no such thing. you have to query separately in each collection